# how to hardcode argument values inside a bash script

Tags: bash

I am automating a process to move directory from host server to target server.
Although its a simple `scp` process, I am stuck at a point where I want to parametrize 2 of the arguments.

I do not want the user to put in the source and target server details (IP or server name). Rather want the user to put in only an Acronym of the server.

e.g. I have 20 servers which are A1 to A8, B1 to B5, C1 to C7
I want the input of the bash script to have 3 arguments i.e. source_server target_server directory_name

e.g.:

```
script_name A7 C2 directory_name
```

inside the bash script I want something like :

```
if $1 = A1 then source = server_IP
else
if $1 = A2 then source = server_IP
```

... and so on

similarly for $2 (target).

and then use the value of source in the SCP command.

Answer (score 2):

Use an associative array:

```
declare -A servers
servers=([a1]=serverA1 [a2]=serverA2 [c1]=serverC1)
src="${servers[$1]}"
dst="${servers[$2]}"
```

Here, the associative array `servers` has your master list of servers.  Since `$1` is the short name for the source server, you can access the long name for the source server with `${servers[$1]}`.

Comment: It's a good solution but I'm sure OP absolutely wanted the full script, including the details he didn't provide.